# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling PUT

Tags: php, youtube-api, fatal-error

Hello i keep getting this fatal error when trying to update tags with the youtube api. am i missing something? thanks

this is the error i keep getting -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=AIzaSyAtyCr7wQNuQU-4eXYToN2rv0fMR6TsR8Y: (400) Bad Request' in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\includes\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:66Stack trace:#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\x\includes\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36): 

Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\x\includes\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186): 

Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\x\includes\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_YouTubeService.php(952): Google_ServiceResource->__call('update', Array)#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\x\includes\insert_tags.php(68): 

Google_VideosServiceResource->update('snippet', Object(Google_Video))#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\x\includes\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php on line 66
```

---

```
<?php
     if(isset($_GET['insertTags']))
     {

 require_once 'channelHeaders.php';
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");  // to get POST data from angular $http
 $request = json_decode($postdata,true); // to convert POST data to array


 // $videoId        = $request['video_id'];
 // $tagsToBeAdded  = $request['new_tags'];

 echo $request['video_id'];
 echo $request['new_tags'];

 echo "<br/>";

 $videoId = $request['video_id'];

 // Create a video list request
 $listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('id,snippet', array(
'id' => $videoId
 ));



 $videoList = $listResponse['items'];
 //var_dump($videoList);

     if (empty($videoList)) {

     echo "Video does not exist.";

     } else {
     // Since a unique video id is given, it will only return 1 video.
     $video = $videoList[0];
     $videoSnippet = $video['snippet'];
     $tags = $videoSnippet['tags'];

     //var_dump($tags);

     }


    if (is_null($tags)) {

    // $tags = array("metal", "even");
    $tags = array($request['new_tags']);
    echo "NULL";

    } else {

    echo "NOT NULL<br/>";
    array_push($tags, $request['new_tags']);
    // array_push($tags, "metal", "even");


    // Construct the Google_Video with the updated tags, hence the snippet
    $updateVideo = new Google_Video($video);
    $updateSnippet = new Google_VideoSnippet($videoSnippet);

    $updateSnippet->setTags($tags);
    $updateVideo -> setSnippet($updateSnippet);


    // Create a video update request

    //ERROR COMES FROM THESE 2 LINES BELOW
    $updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet", $updateVideo);
    $responseTags = $updateResponse['snippet']['tags'];

    echo "success";
    }
 }
```

i've tried a lot of stuff but to no avail, any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: did you find solution?